# como eu posso substituir todos todos os valores negativos de um array no javaScript por 0. EX [-1,2,-3,4] [0,2,0,4]

Tags: javascript, html, array

so consegui fazer isso

```
var numeros = [2, -3, 5, 6, 8];
function sopositivo(n) {
  let index = 0;
  let novo = [];
  for (let i = 0, l = n.length; i < l; i++) {
     if (n[i] < 0) { 
      index = numeros.indexOf[i];
     } if (index !== -1) {
        novo = numeros[index] = 0;
      }
  return novo;
  }
}   

console.log(sopositivo(numeros));
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `map()` retorna um novo array (sem modificar o array já existente) rodando a função callback passada nele para cada item do array.
a função callback que usei tem um if ternário validando se o número é menor que 0.

```
var numeros = [2, -3, 5, 6, 8];
var arrayPositivos = numeros.map((item) => (item < 0) ? 0 : item);
console.log(numeros);
console.log(arrayPositivos);
```

Para mais detalhes consulte: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: obrigado!! vou pesquisar mais a respeito do assunto

Answer (score -3):

Isso você resolve dessa forma

```
        // Entrada
        let numeros = [1, 2, 0, -1]

        for(let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
            if(numeros[i] < 0){
                numeros[i] = 0
            }
        }

        // Saida [1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda1